# What will the temperature on earth be were it to stop spinning?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, earth

How hot will the lit part be and how cold will the unlit? This depends of course on latitude. Also if we take away the atmosphere will the situation be just like on moon?
I talk about a situation with no spinning at all. Is this possible or can we show that the minimal earth day's length is one year?

Comment: The Earth orbits the Sun so even if not spinning it has an effective day of one year. You can still ask your question though, just with the setup that it is spinning in the opposite sense at precisely one revolution a year.

Comment: There's plenty of hypothetical questions on statexchange, akin to "what if a you dropped a ball in a tube that went through the center of Earth," which in fact was a homework problem in an mechanical engineering class when I was getting a degree. I see no reason for hostility towards this question, the asker is simply unlikely to be a native English speaker. Are you really so callous so as to punish people for not being born with the same language as you? They're asking about common phenomena in physics, though it is posed in a crude way, and it has a quantifiable answer.

Comment: There is https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ they would know better. If the earth only had a yearly rotation, the permanent cold side would freeze but might not get quite as cold as the two weeks of shadow on the moon because the atmosphere with greenhouse gases.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would like to tidy up your question just a bit:

> What would the atmospheric temperature distribution look like if the
>   Earth were not rotating (*i.e*. one Earth day were one Earth year).

This is a neat question, but I think that any answer that would come out would be wild speculation.  Second of all, I think that only a rather sophisticated computer simulation could produce an answer that was even close.  The main obstacle to answering this question is that we've never tried this out experimentally, and there's a lot we don't know until we do.

First off, for every latitude on the Earth, we know how much sunlight enters the Earth on the daytime side.  We also have fairly good experimental data about how quickly the atmosphere heats up when the Earth is actually rotating.  We also have fairly reliable data about how fast the Earth's atmosphere cools off on the night time side - when the Earth is rotating.  We don't really have any of this data for a non-rotating Earth.  And we really need this data to have any real chance at answering the question that you ask.

When the Earth's atmosphere begins to heat up or cool off, it begins to "churn" in a variety of ways that are affected by its rotation - the Coriolis effect.  This churning affects the temperature at various latitudes every bit as much as the sunlight itself.

I suppose we could run a computer simulation that used the Navier-Stokes equations to simulate atmosphere heating up and cooling off on a non-rotating Earth.  But this is not at all a question that has a simple one-page solution.

Comment: Can't we at least estimate the amount of energy absorbed by a lit earth and the amount of energy emitted by it based on albedo etc.?